# How to change text in another activity via radio button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I'm new in Java.

I am trying to change the text of a `TextView` to a value according to the `RadioButton` that the user chooses. However, the `RadioGroup` and the `TextView` exist in two separate activities. How do I set the string of the `TextView` to the `RadioButton` chosen in the previous activity?

Comment: pass state of radioButton to next activity and change the text based on state of RadioButton

Comment: Can you add to your post some sample code of what you tried and the behavior you observe that is different than what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an `Intent` in your first class:

`Intent intent = new Intent(YourFirstClass.this,YourRecievingClass.class);`

then pass the extra:

`intent.putExtra("radiobuttontext", yourStringValue);`

^ The `yourStringValue` should be a string of the chosen radiobutton. You can get that with `RadioGroup#setOnCheckedChangeListener`. For example, in your class with the radio buttons:

```
yourRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int val) {

            if(firstButton.isChecked())
                yourStringValue = firstButton.getText().toString();
            else if(secondButton.isChecked())
                yourStringValue = secondButton.getText().toString();
            else
                yourStringValue = thirdButton.getText().toString();
        }
        });
```

In your second Activity, you need to `get` the extra. After you do, you can use `TextView#setText` to set it to your `TextView`:

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("radiobuttontext");
yourTextView.setText(value);
```